# Connecting to a OpenVPN Connect server breaks IPv6

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

So I've got an OpenVPN Connect server which doesn't have IPv6 enabled on it, It shouldn't actually be doing any IPv6, when I connect to it, I lose IPv6 connectivity on my host.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping internet_ipv6_server -t

Pinging internet_ipv6_server [redacted] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from redacted: time=26ms
...
VPN Connects and then:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
```

[image: My network settings]

This is what my network settings look like, on the left is my main network adapter and on the right is the TAP Adapter for the OpenVPN Connect 2.1.1.102 Client

I had a brief look in my OpenVPN logs and found that it was pushing 3 IPv6 routes:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add route 2000::/4 interface=1 store=active
netsh interface ipv6 add route 3000::/4 interface=1 store=active
netsh interface ipv6 add route fc00::/7 interface=1 store=active
```

If anyone has any ideas/suggestions or solutions they'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you don't want this? Usually you _do_. Who runs this VPN?

Comment: What does your OpenVPN config look like?  You could probably do a `route-nopull` and you wouldn't get any changes to your route table, but then you would need to manually add any other routes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The VPN only allows access to a dev environment, I don't route all my traffic through it.

Comment: So, I changed to using the OpenVPN Client and it works now but if I use the OpenVPN Connect client then it doesn't work